# Disabling relaxation: it will not work with multiple definitions

Tags: atmel

i'm a beginner to coding and yesterday i code a simple light up led in C programming , it works in Atmel Studio, however the next day it has these errors from the picture shown. My code is

```
#define F_CPU 1600000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
int main(void)
{
    DDRB=0xFF;
    
    while (1)
    {
        PORTB |= 0b0000100;

        }
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RARim.png)

I'm not sure how as I keep trying to find help from internet, but it couldnt help me

Comment: For whatever reason, it seems you have more than one `main` function.  The error is presumably in the build part, not in the code shown.  For example, if you provide the same module twice, such an error could occur.

Answer (score 0):

PORTB |= 0b0000100;
This looks like 7 digit only. It should be of 8 digit like
PORTB |= **0b00001000**;

Try and mark answer if it helps.